# How can I draw a regression line in log scale?

Tags: regression, plotting

The supplied code draws some data points and the corresponding regression line.

The regression line goes through or is near most of the data points on a linear scale.

[image]

.

However, on a log scale, the line doesn't look very accurate. Also, the lengths of the lines become shorter.

[image]

**How can I make the regression line look same in both the linear scale and log scale?**

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ZedGraph;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class GenerateRegressionLine
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string dataFilePath = @"output.txt";
        Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> givenLine = Fit.ReadDataFromFile(dataFilePath);

        Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> regressionLine = CreateRegressionLine(givenLine.Item1, givenLine.Item2);

        
        ZedGraphControl zgc = new ZedGraphControl();
        zgc.Size = new Size(1200, 800);

        GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;
        myPane.Title.Text = "Line Plot";
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "X Axis";
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Y Axis";

        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Log;
        myPane.YAxis.Type = AxisType.Log;

        PointPairList givenLinePPL = new PointPairList(givenLine.Item1.ToArray(), givenLine.Item2.ToArray());
        LineItem givenLineCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Given Line", givenLinePPL, Color.Green, SymbolType.None);

        PointPairList regressionLinePPL = new PointPairList(regressionLine.Item1.ToArray(), regressionLine.Item2.ToArray());
        LineItem regressionLineCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Regression Line", regressionLinePPL, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);


        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Invalidate();

        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(dataFilePath);

        string imagePath = Path.Combine(directory, "DrawRegressionLine.png");

        zgc.GetImage().Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }

    private static Tuple<double, double> CalculateLinearRegressionCoefficients(List<double> xList, List<double> yList)
    {
        if (xList == null || yList == null || xList.Count != yList.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException("Lists must be non-null and have the same number of elements.");

        double xSum = 0, ySum = 0, xySum = 0, x2Sum = 0;
        int count = xList.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            double x = xList[i];
            double y = yList[i];
            xSum += x;
            ySum += y;
            xySum += x * y;
            x2Sum += x * x;
        }

        double slope = (count * xySum - xSum * ySum) / (count * x2Sum - xSum * xSum);
        double intercept = (ySum - slope * xSum) / count;

        return Tuple.Create(intercept, slope);
    }

    public static Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> CreateRegressionLine(List<double> xList, List<double> yList)
    {
        // Calculate the regression coefficients
        var coefficients = CalculateLinearRegressionCoefficients(xList, yList);

        List<double> xVals = new List<double>();
        List<double> yVals = new List<double>();

        double intercept = coefficients.Item1;
        double slope = coefficients.Item2;

        double startX = xList[0];
        double endX = xList[xList.Count - 1];

        xVals.Add(startX);
        yVals.Add(intercept + slope * startX);

        xVals.Add(endX);
        yVals.Add(intercept + slope * endX);

        return Tuple.Create(xVals, yVals);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal exactly here? Linear regression has a precise, uniquely defined mathematical sense. If you want something that "looks good", it will inevitably be different. At that point it would be wrong to call it "the linear regression line": it would be a line that looks good but is drawn using a statistically dubious procedure. Or would you like instead to be reassured by an explanation that regression lines may be correct and yet look wrong in log-space?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, *Or would you like instead to be reassured by an explanation that regression lines may be correct and yet look wrong in log-space?* --- Yes.

Comment: It looks to me like you are doing something very wrong here.  What exactly is the line in the second plot supposed to be?  It doesn't appear to be a fit to the logs of the y values, and it's definitely not a log transform of the line that was fit in the first plot (a log transform of a straight line will not itself be a straight line).  So, what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much time, but I'll attempt an explanation.

#### Short version

That regression line looks correct; it is perfectly normal that regression lines might look wonky when you plot them in log-space, because the distances are altered.

#### Long version

If the green data points are $(x_1,y_1), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$, then the red line is $ax+b$ where $a,b$ are chosen so that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |ax_i+b - y_i|^2
$$
is minimized.

$ax_i+b - y_i$ is the vertical distance between the green data points and the points with the same $x$ coordinate on the red line, in the first plot (linear scale). Hence that line is designed to "look good" in the first plot; those are the distances used.

For instance, let us just focus on two of your data points for simplicity: on the green line I can read off something like (50,3) (first data point) and (1300, 700) (penultimate data point). The red line goes through something like (50,100) and (1300,600). (I read these values from the plot, so they are probably just crude approximations). The two corresponding summands are |3-100|^2 and |700-600|^2. Note that those two distances are about 100, the same for both points. Taking any other line in place of the red line would have given a larger total sum-of-squares (counting not only these two summands but the ones corresponding to all data points).

When you go to log-space, however distances are altered in a non-linear fashion.

That distance between $\log_{10} 3$ and $\log_{10} 100$ is about 1.5, reflecting the fact that the two numbers differ by 1.5 orders of magnitude.  This is much larger than the distance between $\log_{10} 600$ and $\log_{10} 700$, which have the same order of magnitude.

In particular, when values become smaller, their distance is stretched in log space: the distance between 3 and 0.3 is the same as the distance between 3000 and 300.  That's why you see very different distances in the second plot, especially associated to the /small/ data points, those on the left.

The red line is designed to "look good" in the first space, not in the second space.

If you run a regression in log space, you can find another line that best approximates the green data points in log space. That's the one that minimizes
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |a \log(x_i)+b - \log(y_i)|^2.
$$
This one is going to look good in the second plot, but not in the first.

If you want, you can also find a line that minimizes the sum of the squared distances over /both/ plots, and hence it looks "less wrong" in both; for instance by minimizing
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |ax_i+b - y_i|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n |a \log(x_i)+b - \log(y_i)|^2.
$$
as a function of $a,b$. That's still an easy task, because it's just another quadratic function of $a,b$.

#### The statistics

However, from the point of view of a statistician, that third line would look like a very dubious choice. That's because each minimization corresponds to a different error model. The regression line in you have plotted assumes that your observed data points come from a process that produces points of the form $y_i = ax_i + b + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i$ is an error on each data point. Those $a,b$ are chosen as to minimize the sums of the squared errors.

Running a linear regression on the second plot in log scale, instead, would assume that your observed data points come from a process of the form $\log y_i = a\log x_i + b + \varepsilon_i$, or $y_i = 10^b x_i^a 10^{\varepsilon_i}$. In particular, that is a *multiplicative* error rather than an *additive* error that you want to minimize.

So the question you should ask yourself here is: what do my errors look like? Is an error that perturbs $1$ to $1.5$ as likely as one that perturbs $10$ to $10.5$, or as likely as one that perturbs $10$ to $15$?

The third mixed regression assumes an even weirder error model, which is probably not realistic at all.

Comment: Apparently, your hypothesis is incorrect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77714041/drawing-a-regression-line-in-c-sharp

Comment: @user366312 I don't know how you produced them, but it's clear that the red lines in the two plots aren't the same. One goes close to (40,100) and the other to (40,15). It seems like you're doing linear regression in log-scale in the first image on the SO post (i.e., $a,b$ that minimize my 2nd formula).